# Can 1080p resolution be achieved with < PCIe x16?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I have a 2010-ish Dell Precision T7500 with 4 physical PCIe x16 slots, but, electrically, two of the slots are only wired for x4 and x8 speeds.

Right now, I have an nVidia Quadro NVS 295. It's an x16 card but physically fits in the x4 and x8 slots. The card works fine in the x16 slots, but when it's in either of the slower slots, it restricts the resolution to `1440x900` maximum. I would like to have `1920x1080` resolution. Is this possible on an x4 or x8 PCIe slot?

I'm asking because I would like to use the two x16 slots to hold Nvidia Tesla M2090's.

Comment: I believe its not an electricity restriction but a bandwidth restriction that you're up against.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. However, I just found a PCIe x8 video card that can do up to 2560 x 1600 resolution at 120 Hz, the ZOTAC GeForce GT 730. My card is much less powerful, so I don't think bandwidth is a restriction. For another example see the Gigabyte GV-N730SL-2GL GeForce GT 730.

Comment: Did you check the monitor can it do 1080p, because a lot of times the video card detects the max resolution of the monitor and sets it to that.

Comment: Yes, it can, I can achieve 1080p no problem when the card is in the x16 slot.

Comment: @CedarMora When people talk about "powerful graphics cards" they are not talking about electricity consumption, rather they are talking about the speed of the card. This is a combination of bandwidth and processing speed. The high end cards do use more electricity, however newer lower range cards can be just as "powerful" and use less electricity due to the advances in technology making it more energy efficient.

Comment: Right, I don't mean electricity usage, I just mean bandwidth.

Comment: What OS? this really feels like a possible driver issue

Comment: Windows 10 professional. It was previously Windows 7 Professional, but it had the same issue then. I am going to try a BIOS update, as suggested by Wes Sayeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of lanes available to a PCIe slot only determines the maximum amount of bandwidth available between the video card and the motherboard and has nothing to do with the maximum resolution a video card can display.

Resolution is determined by the amount of memory the card has and the connection type to the screen (VGA, DVI, etc.)

An x16 slot can fill the video card's memory much faster than an x4 slot can, so it will perform much better when playing games or doing heavy 3D work.  But when it comes to just putting pixels on the screen, even a 1x slot has more than enough bandwidth to accomplish that.

The NVS 295 is a very old chipset; designed for business graphics, not 3D gaming.  Your resolution issues with that card are probably due to the drivers or the way you're connecting the display (VGA perhaps?), or some other configuration issue.

Proof?  Consider this PCIe 1x video card from HIS (http://www.hisdigital.com/un/product2-675.shtml).  It's a Radeon 6450, which outclasses an NVS 295 by several years.  The specs for that card supports 2560x1600.

Comment: I can achieve 1080p without any trouble when it is in the x16 slot.

Comment: But can you still get 1080p from the Quadros if the Teslas are in the slower slots?

Comment: I think the Teslas have to occupy the two x16 slots, so I would need to put the Quadro in either the x8 or x4 slots. I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: So you're saying that right now you only have the one Quadro card and not the Tesla?  And the Quadro card works in full res in the x16 slot but not in the x4 or x8 slot?

Comment: Yes to both questions. The reason I am asking the question is because I have one Tesla in the mail and am considering getting a second one, but not if the Quadro won't function properly when placed into the available x8 or x4 slots.

Comment: That's very peculiar. I suspect this might be an issue with Dell's firmware. They've had issues like that before. Try upgrading the BIOS.  Also, I reworded your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do and why.  That way you'll get fewer responses from people trying to explain PCIe to you.

Comment: It could also be a problem if you have a KVM between the card and the monitor. I've seen an old KVM that restricted the resolution to 1280x1024 even though the card and monitor supported higher resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, that makes the questions much clearer. My brain is fried right now, I'm not really thinking very clearly. I'll see what I can find as far as BIOS updates. You've been a great help, thanks so much.

Comment: The card outputs displayport, which goes into a converter to dvi-d, which goes into the monitor. However, I don't think the converter is the problem, since it works fine when the Quadro is in the x16 slot.

Comment: I just did the BIOS update, and it works flawlessly now! Woohoo! Thanks so very much, Wes, I really appreciate it. Specifically, I chose BIOS version A14, for any future readers.

Answer (score 1):

> Can 1080p resolution be acheived with < PCIe x16?

Ofcourse it can.  If you want you you use ISA and reach 1080p. You almost need no bandwidth for a nice static image, even at 1080p.

> I have an Nvidia Quadro NVS 295, which is made for an x16 slot, 
>   but will fit in the x8 and x4 slots.

As well as x1 slots.

> Although it works in both the x4 and x8 slots, it restricts the resolution
>   to 1440 x 900 maximum.

That is an insane choice in the driver. Not a hard limitation.

> I would like to have 1920 x 1080 resolution. Is this possible, given an
>   electrically x8 or x4 PCIe slot?

Yes, -almost- any card and driver combination will do this.

Comment: So sounds more like a driver issue then?

Comment: Aye. Badwitth for just some resolution is about nul. YOu want a bit more if you want to update it, but even PCIe 1.0 x1 will do just fine for 2D.  You only need more for gaming, CUDa etc etc. But just showing a picture, a browser windows, ssh client, email, ..... almost no bandwidth needed. Something else is the problem, not bandwidth,

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll check out the different drivers available then.